# ANTLR4 adaptivePredict going to wrong Semantic Predicate?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a grammar with semantic predicates somewhat simplified like this:

```
startrule:
  {<condition1 in C++>}? rule1 |
  {<condition2 in C++>}? rule2 
  ;  

rule1:
  {<condition1.1 in C++>}? rule1_statement1 |
  {<condition1.2 in C++>}? rule1_statement2 
  ;

rule2:
  {<condition2.1 in C++>}? rule2_statement1 |
  {<condition2.2 in C++>}? rule2_statement2 
  ;
```

If `condition1` or `condition2` are evaluated to true, it correctly goes to `rule1` or `rule2`. So the semantic predicates are working so far, but the problem I'm seeing is that, for example:

- rule2 is executed
- condition2.1 is false
- condition2.2 is true (it should go to `rule2_statement2`)

When I see the Cpp code, I see this line:

`switch (getInterpreter<atn::ParserATNSimulator>()->adaptivePredict(_input, 531, _ctx)) {`

And then a `case` for each corresponding statement. When the code is executed, even if `condition2.1` is false, it enters the `case` for `rule2_statement1` (instead of the `case` for `rule2_statement2`). So it seems as if the semantic predicates are not working there?.

And since that code has a check for the condition like this:

```
if (!(condition2.1)) throw FailedPredicateException(this, "condition2.1");
```

It throws a FailedPredicate exception, my ErrorStrategy `recover` just calls the DefaultErrorStrategy `recover`, which eventually crashes because LL1Analyzer::_LOOK throws an out of range exception.

Any hint as to why some semantic predicates appear not to be working? rule2_statement1 and rule2_statement2 have the same tokens but different embedded actions.

Regards,
JZ

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I had an issue in m C++ code with the conditions...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).